# Ownership of user comments posted on news websites and third-party use

Tags: legal

Can a third party use user comments posted on news websites for data mining purposes without explicit permission from the users or the news website, particularly for the following countries: USA, UK, India.

The comments wouldn't be reproduced or reprinted in their original format, and personal user information would not be required.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the website's privacy policy or terms of use. If they have explicitly stated that every content written or produced is strictly reserved, then I do think they "should not" be reproduced.

But you see, as long as the content is visible to people, there is a chance that somebody will scrape the content. There is nothing much you can do about it.